# Ionic3-Cordova-UWP : Ionic Storage doesn’t work when app is running

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, uwp

I have a problem with Ionic storage in my Ionic App for Windows (UWP app). I already tested and deployed my app for Android without any trouble. 
Now I would like to generate an UWP app.

The app I’m developing is a workshop’s dashboard. The indicators change every day and I need to save them from one day to another. To do this I usethe storage module of Ionic.

When launching the command

```
$ionic serve
```

the app responds exactly as it should in the web browser (Firefox). From one launch to another my data are still there. 
When I use

```
 $ionic cordova run windows
```

the installation and launch steps of my app work fine. Every function of my app runs fine, but the call to storage (get and set) doesn’t work : when I close, and then reopen it as an autonomous application, I loose all data every time. It is the same when I run the app from Visual Studio.

Moreover, I write some console.log in the result of the promise and none of them is written in the Javascript console. It is like Windows does not recognize the command.

I tried with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and Visual Studio 2017, the result is identical. I followed the recommendation of Ionic Doc and add the target platform windows10 in the config.xml.

Does anyone have an idea of what I’m doing wrong ? Is there an incompatibility between Windows and Ionic ?
Thanks for any help.

Config :

```
Windows 10 64-bits
Ionic CLI: 3.19.1
Cordova CLI : 8.0.0
Node : v6.11.2
Visual Studio Community 2017 (15.5.27130.2036)
```

Extract of my code maPage.ts :

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export class maPage {

constructor(public storage: Storage) {

    this.downloadData();
}

ionViewWillLeave()
{
  this.saveData();
}

TabData = {
         id: 0,
         label: '',
         Tab1: [],
         Tab2: [],
         attri1 : 0,
         attri2: false
       }
Param = {
    Objet1: {NbObj1: 7},
    Objet2: {NbObj2: 5}
  }

saveData()
{   
    var Data: object;
    Data = 
    {
      TData: this.TabData,
      TParam: this.Param
    }
    this.storage.set('Data', Data).then(_=> {
      console.log('Backup done!');    
    }, error => {
      console.log('erreur : ', JSON.stringify(error))
    });
}

downloadData()
{
  this.storage.ready().then(()=>{
    console.log('storage ready');
    this.storage.get('Data').then((val) => {
      this.TabData = val.TData;
      this.Param = val.TParam;
      console.log('Récupération terminée !');
    }).catch(erreur => {  
      console.log('La variable Data est vide ou n\'existe pas!');
      console.log('erreur : ', JSON.stringify(erreur));
   }).catch(err => {
      console.log('storage not ready');
      console.log('err : ', JSON.stringify(err));
   });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows platform, console.log is not supported. To do that, you should install `cordova-plugin-console`, or need to use `alert function`.

Regarding storage, I am suggesting you could use `localstorage` or `cordova-sqlite-storage`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I finally choose to use localstorage and it's work ! However I don't understand why Ionic Storage doesn't work on Windows platform... And I actually add the plugin 'cordova-plugin-console' but forgot to install it with npm.... It's fine too. Thx !